# High RDS CPU Utilization By Select Query

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I am using a query for finding my results. My table has almost 2000000 records.
Each time when query is executing it's taking high CPU.
Can anybody help me to get out of this?

I am using below query as:

```
select * from demo.document_details 
where udid ilike '06AAACT2727Q1Z0:HR1000249801:%' 
  and active='Y' 
  and ewb_no=''
```

## Query Plan is :

```
Seq Scan on document_details  (cost=0.00..469135.94 rows=86 width=1132) (actual time=1711.248..2116.794 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: (((udid)::text ~~ '06AAACT2727Q1Z0:HR1000249801:%'::text) AND ((active)::text = 'Y'::text) AND ((ewb_no)::text = ''::text))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 2047478
Planning time: 0.348 ms
Execution time: 2116.870 ms
```

Comment: it would be useful if you were to provide the table definition, or provided the output of "explain analyze [query]" - you could use https://explain.depesz.com/ for this

Comment: Is `document_details` a table or a view?

Comment: @404 it's a table not view

Answer (score 0):

You need an index.  If your collation is not 'C', then then index should specify "text_pattern_ops", so that it can support the prefix matching.

```
create index on demo.document_details (udid text_pattern_ops);
```

You might also include "active" and "ewb_no" in the index, depending on how selective those columns are, and whether most of your queries which search on "udid" also include those.  If you do include them, you should include them in the index before "udid", because using the LIKE for a prefix is basically a range criterion, and once you have a range criterion on an indexed column, it greatly impairs the utility of columns occuring after it in the index definition. (Imagine the difference between looking in phone book for "Joh%, James" and "Johnson, J%").

Comment: I already created the index as:CREATE INDEX dd_udid
    ON demo.document_details USING btree
    (udid COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DESC)
    TABLESPACE pg_default; Is there need to drop this and create new index using text_pattern_ops.Please suggest me.

Comment: Probably.  You don't **need** to drop the existing one, you can have both indexes at the same time, but the one without text_pattern_ops is likely unneeded once you build the second one. It could be useful if you ever want to sort results by the default collation.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes I did indexing as you suggested.It helps me to reduce query time and CPU utilization upto some extent.